# 'Provided Schema does not match Table' despite the schema matching table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, terraform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm currently running an Airflow DAG that takes extract data from a MySQL backend and saves the CSV into a GCS directory, then uploads from the GCS dir to a BigQuery staging table. The BQ Table schema is held inside a Terraform infrastructure.

When I run the load task that takes the CSV's from GCS and imports then to BQ I get this error despite the mentioned schema having the field necessary:

> BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Provided Schema does not match Table project:us_operational_data_staging.fis_account. Field fis_account_id is missing in new schema'}.

When I go into the file uploaded into GCS, it has the correct schema. Likewise when I go into terraform and look at the staging schema, it also has the correct schema.

EDIT: Here is the Terraform code

```
#dataset
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "uk_operational_data_staging" {
  dataset_id    = "uk_operational_data_staging"
  friendly_name = "uk_operational_data_staging"
  description   = "A dataset for staging data from our uk operational database backend"
  location      = "EU"
  project       = var.project

  labels = {
    "env"        = "data-prod"
    "created_by" = "terraform"
  }
}
```

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "uk_fis_account_staging" {
  dataset_id  = google_bigquery_dataset.uk_operational_data_staging.dataset_id
  table_id    = "fis_account"
  project     = var.project
  description = "Staging table for fis_account table"
  schema      = file("./bigquery_schema/operational_data_staging/fis_account_staging_schema.json")
}
```

Here is part of the schema:

```
[
    {
        "name": "fis_account_id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "user_id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "parent_id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
etc etc
```

Please help!!

Comment: Can you share your terraform code?

Comment: @MarkoE I've added the terraform code and part of the schema to the original post now!

Comment: AFAIK, file reads the content of the file and returns a **string**. So you could in theory try to come up with a way to read the file as-is, e.g. maybe with https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/file.

Comment: Or maybe using `jsonencode(file(...))` would work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MarkoE I've been told that BQ has been able to read the schema from the Terraform file(path) function shown above

Comment: Are you able to simply [append/overwrite](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data) from your CSV in GCS to the existing table (eg: from the Console) using that same json schema or does it fail in the same way?